# Passing value to function from html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a value from html to a function but when I do I get an error - reference error: cant find the variable: "var value". The code below I'm removing spaces and replacing them with underscores then trying to pass that to a function called onToDate.

```
var theFunction2 = theFunction.replace(/ /g,"_");

$('#inserted').append('<div id="'+theFunction2+'"><li onclick="onToDate('+theFunction2+')"><img width="30px" height="25px" src="style/soccer.png"><div id="popupContactClose2">'+counted+'</div></img>'+ rs.rows.item(0)['playing']+'</li>');
```

onToDate is simply there to alert the value passed to it:

```
function onToDate(hello){        

alert(''+hello+'');
console.log(''+hello+'');
}
```

This is where I get the error. I don't really get whats happening I've used this before and it worked fine.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Comment: A LI element inside a DIV element? And a DIV element inside an IMG element? That's not valid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onclick="onToDate('+theFunction2+');
```

is turning into something like:

```
onToDate(some_thing);
```

so in the above case, `some_thing` is a variable that is `undefined`, meaning that this is a  Reference error.

So,

```
onclick="onToDate(\"'+theFunction2+'\");
```

should fix it

Answer (score 1):

First of all @IAbstractDownvoteFactor is right. You should fix `onclick` definiton.

If this code runs in `$(document).ready()` block, then your `onToDate` function is not accesible from that scope. Your `click` event calls from global scope. You should define it like this;

```
window.onToDate = function(hello){
    alert(hello);
}
```

And no need for those single quotes...